# I can not set python version in PyScripter

Tags: python, pyscripter

I want to set python version in PyScripter (.../Run/Python Versions/Setup Python). During setting I get the following instruction:

[image].

Does it mean, that in folder with python installation have to be folder with python environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the folder that is python installed.

Comment: yes, but after folder selection is list versions empty